# Define import path at compile time with webpack define plugin

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to define the path of an import statement at compile time in a webpack build.  The path is defined by a configuration file that can change with every build.

I'm using DefinePlugin, but without any luck so far:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __PATH__: JSON.stringify('./path/to/src')
  })
]
```

And then in compiled code:

```
import Foo from __PATH__
```

Running webpack then results in a `Module parse failed: Unexpected token` error, obviously because `__PATH__` is not a valid path string. I expected that the `__PATH__` token would be replaced with the string from the DefinePlugin options.

Is this sort of thing possible? Am I going about it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with an alias:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    ‘@alias’: ‘./path/to/arc‘
  }
}
```